# How to do join with SUM in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, join, aggregate

Let's say I have two simple models

```
project
   t.string :title

vote
   t.references :project
   t.integer :value
```

When I do loop throuh all projects, I also want to include sum of all votes, because doing

```
projects = Project.all

foreach project in projects
    sum = project.votes.sum(:value)
    ...
```

isn't really effective.

Is there any way how to do this without manualy writing the SQL? Something like

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(v.value)
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN votes v
ON v.project_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this gets computed frequently, you're probably better off keeping a summary statistic in the project record (total_votes).  You can either update on each vote, or update via a cron job.

I think you're looking for the following though:

```
@totals = Vote.sum(:value,:group=>:project_id)
@projects = Project.find(:all)
```

then

`<%=h @project.title %> has <%= @totals[@project.id] %> votes.`

Comment: actually, I was looking for something like in the query, see edit

Comment: My suggestion will return an OrderedHash of project_id=>sum, you can couple that with a Project.find(:all) and assemble the data pretty easily. I don't think rails has support for returning something that complex without using raw SQL